# select all the customers who had records on each month

Tags: sql, hiveql

How to select all the customers who has records for each month? 
Here customer will be chosen,because he/she had records for every month.

```
+----------+--------+-------+
| customer |  date  | spend |
+----------+--------+-------+
| a        | 201801 |   5.5 |
| b        | 201801 |    16 |
| c        | 201801 |     7 |
| a        | 201802 |   3.2 |
| b        | 201802 |   4.6 |
| a        | 201803 |     3 |
| c        | 201803 |   1.2 |
+----------+--------+-------+
```

desired output:

```
+----------+--------+-------+
| customer |  date  | spend |
+----------+--------+-------+
| a        | 201801 |   5.5 |
| a        | 201802 |   3.2 |
| a        | 201803 |     3 |
+----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: is this your date formet? please provide a desire output

Comment: What you tried so far? How you define each month? Does it mean distinct month in table?

Comment: @TaimurKhan I will extract month from date and group by customer and month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one record per month per customer:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by customer) as cnt
      from t
     ) t cross join
     (select count(distinct date) as cnt
      from t
     ) tt
where t.cnt = tt.cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do like this:

```
select * 
from customers
group by customer, date, spend 
having count(distinct month(date)) = 
                   (select count(distinct month(date))
                    from customers
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the rows have dates for 2018, with this:

```
select customer from customers
group by customer
having count(distinct date) = 12
```

you can get all the customers that have rows for every month of 2018. 
So you need to join it to the main table:

```
select c.* from (
  select customer from customers
  group by customer
  having count(distinct date) = 12
) t inner join customers c
on c.customer = t.customer
order by c.customer, c.date
```

If there are dates for other years too:

```
select c.* from (
  select customer from customers
  where substr(date, 1, 4) = '2018'
  group by customer
  having count(distinct date) = 12
) t inner join customers c
where substr(c.date, 1, 4) = '2018'
on c.customer = t.customer
order by c.customer, c.date
```